# Changing default dropdown value in SAP CRM Web UI

Tags: webui, sap-crm

I want to change default values which gets populated in the below picture.

[image]

I tried modifying get_v_role method but it didn't serve my purpose.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In personalize->personalize settings, there is sort option. It sometimes overwrites this arrangement of values of get_v method.
Also code can be written in inbound plug of this view. I did it for overview page drop down and it worked. You can try for your search page.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering/changing drop-down value of search parameter, You've to Re-define GET_DQUERY_DEFINITIONS method of ZCL_XXX_IMPL class of component. GET_V_XX methods are only used to modify drop-down/F4 help of view pages not the search view.

**STEPS:**

1. Click F2 while placing the cursor on Account ID(for which parameter you want 
   to modify) drop-down.
2. Go to BSP Component using t-code - BSP_WD_CMPWB
3. Enter the component name and Enhancement set
4. Select the view.

[image]

5. Go to Implementation class .

[image]

If your component is enhanced then it will be having ZCL_XXX_IMPL class. otherwise you've to enhance that component. Click on that class.

6. After that find GET_DQUERY_DEFINITIONS method and implement same way as 
   GET_V_XXX.